# Raw f-string SyntaxError

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, f-string, rawstring

I'm trying to build a regex with a raw f-string in a Sublime Text 3.2.2 plugin:

```
operatorSymbols = "==|!="
print(fr'\s*({operatorSymbols})\s*')
```

Desired output:

```
\s*(==|!=)\s*
```

I get the error:

```
    print(fr'\s*({operatorSymbols})\s*')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Wrong Python version?

Comment: My guess too @tripleee – that the user is using an older version of python

Comment: Specifically, f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. For compatibility with earlier versions, stick with `%` or `.format()`.

Comment: which python version are you using, unable to reproduce it in python 3.6.8

Comment: Could reproduce it with Python 2.7.3 but not with 3.6.8.
Should be fixed by using newer Python version!

Comment: Turns out that Sublime Text 3.2.2 plugins use Python 3.3